# Jquery dropdown hover effect

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having problem with my jquery dropdown hover effect. For some reason the dropdown container moves up. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#dropdown_container").slideDown();
    });
    $("#dropdown_container").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#dropdown_container").slideUp();
    });
});
```

[Rest of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/cf9Yv/7/)

Rememeber to select the jquery framework in the menu

Comment: No it is not, it moves down.

Comment: your html code has unclosed tags. For me it works.. When exactly you have problem?

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: @Christian When you hover over the checkout button i want to show the dropdown_container. At the moment its now working well the container moves up

Comment: @Sebastian but the `dropdown_container` must be behind or below the submit?

Comment: @Christin No it doesnt have to i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set `margin-top` for your `#dropdown_container` for example:

```
#dropdown_container {
   margin-top: 35px;
}
```

hope this works!

Comment: do you have any advice on how to improve the jquery hover effect it doesnt respond to well sometimes on mouseleave

Comment: Actually this is because you are detecting `mouseleave` only on `#dropdown_container`, you should also use it on `#submit`. For example: `$("#submit").mouseleave(function(){
  $("#dropdown_container").slideUp();
 });`

Answer (score 0):

Try animating your containers padding-bottom to grow down in size like so, and tell me if it works for you:

```
    $("#submit").on("mouseenter",function(){
       $("#dropdown_container").animate({"padding-bottom":"200px"}, fast);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `float: left` to `#dropdown_container`:

```
#dropdown_container {
   float: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/v7WUy/)